# Trouble getting Conky to Display Japanese Characters on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, conky, openbox, unicode, japanese

I run xubuntu with Openbox and I'm having trouble getting conky to play ball with japanese characters. All of the advice I've found through looking on the internet has been unhelpful and does not seem to resolve the problem. Below I've posted my conky.conf file for people to peek at and perhaps give insight as to how I can resolve the problem

Cheers

```
alignment br
background no
border_width 1
cpu_avg_samples 2
default_color white
default_outline_color white
default_shade_color white
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
draw_outline no
draw_shades no
use_xft yes
xftfont WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono:size=12
override_utf8_locale yes
gap_x 5
gap_y 60
minimum_size 5 5
net_avg_samples 2
no_buffers yes
out_to_console no
out_to_stderr no
extra_newline no
own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_type desktop
stippled_borders 0
update_interval 1.0
uppercase no
use_spacer none
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no
TEXT
GrandpaCompy ${color dark red}Uptime:$color $uptime
$hr
${if_mpd_playing}
${font WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono:size=12}${color dark red}${scroll 20 $mpd_title.}
${font WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono:size=12}$color${scroll 20 $mpd_artist.}
${font WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono:size=12}${scroll 20 $mpd_album.}
$mpd_elapsed/$mpd_length
$mpd_status
$hr
${color dark red}RAM Usage:$color $mem/$memmax - $memperc% ${membar 4}
${color dark red}Swap Usage:$color $swap/$swapmax - $swapperc% ${swapbar 4}
${color dark red}CPU Usage:$color $cpu% ${cpubar 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, finally I solved it by forcing conkyrc enconding to UTF-8 and by pointing to the correct font supporting Japanese.

Check if your config file is encoded with UTF-8:

```
file -bi ~/.conkyrc
```

you should get

> text/plain; charset=utf-8

then, check that your font is correctly installed and that your are refering to it correctly:

```
fc-list
```

So just depending on the font you have installed, select the correct text. In my case, I just added this to the config (new conky's LUA config style):

```
font = 'IPAGothic,IPAゴシック:style=Regular:size=9',
```

Or directly within the text:

```
${font Source Han Sans JP Heavy,源ノ角ゴシック JP Heavy:style=Heavy:size=9}広島のお好み焼きおたくです
```

it does work as well with

> 'Source Han Sans JP:style=Regular' 
>   and 'HanaMinA,花園明朝A:style=Regular'

HTH